# How to raise an immediate sigalarm in c

Tags: c, alarm

I know i can set an alarm to "go off" with a SIGALRM after a specified amount of time using `alram(numberOfSeconds)` what i am looking to do is to raise the SIGALRM immediately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`raise(SIGALRM);`